# PHP mysql_connection close

Tags: php, database, odbc

I am new to PHP but I am strong in classic ASP, so I am based on classic ASP to learn and pickup PHP.

Since I have only one database to connect, so I created a function to connect to it and return record set, then I want to close the record set after I finished with it.  (I am following my classic ASP practice)

I made a function to connect to ODBC then the function will return the RS as follow:

```
function connection_open($strSQL)
{
$conn=odbc_connect('dbreadonly','dbreadonly','readonly');
if (!$conn)
  {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
$myRS=odbc_exec($conn,$strSQL);
return $myRS;
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM TblUsers";
$rs=connection_open($sql);
if (!$rs)
  {exit("Error in SQL");}
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
  {
  $username=odbc_result($rs,"UserName");
  echo "<td>$username</td></tr>";
  }
```

Now, how do I close the connection if outside the function?

Comment: its a scope issue, `$conn` exists inside that function only. also `$rs` is never defined

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line. Correction done